# Hardware Bluetooth devices providing tongue-smartphone interface

Tags: keyboards, smartphones, bluetooth, tablet, brain-computer-interface

As there is some medication that deeply sedates patients, leaving them only able to eat and move the tongue, I was wondering if there are or if anyone has the intention to produce hardware mouth devices with buttons operable via the tongue (which, despite sedation, can still be moved), to operate a mobile phone via Bluetooth (the arms and hands will be sedated, and the user will be too tired to use them).

Such a device would also be compatible with other types of disability, such as users with no hands or users going through some form of neurological paralyzing dysfunction, as there are many such medical conditions.

I would appreciate it if someone could design, implement, and seem such hardware.

It doesn't seem to be available on there market at the moment.

Thanks.